# How to debug while running from GoLand Terminal

Tags: debugging, go, terminal, goland

Is possible to debug from terminal (included in GoLand IDE), what I want to do is to stop in a break point when you run a .go file from the terminal.
This because I want to run the script sending parameters to go to validate if parameters has been received to the .go script.

[GoLand Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTwNT.png)

[GoLand Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBRri.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to debug from GoLand! For me next approach is the best:

1) For example we have `x.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    name, ending := "World", "!"
    ending2 := `)`
    fmt.Printf("Hello %s %s%s \n", name, ending, ending2)
}
```

2) Edit your debug configuration:

[image]

3) Run in console next command:

```
go build -gcflags='-N -l' x.go \
    && dlv --listen=:2345 --headless=true --api-version=2 exec ./x
```

4) Now place your breakpoint and hit "debug" button.

**[Here](https://monosnap.com/file/aDJXVaE2EM1kb9GdjID70XDo9M0XHQ)** you can find **video** how it looks for me.

Comment: @JavierSalas Glad, that it helped you!

Comment: Can you please help me understand why you are using the terminal instead of letting the IDE build the project? Do we need to improve something there? Thank you.

Comment: @dlsniper Hey. Because it won't work( Here you can find video: https://monosnap.com/file/2kVZ2NVQzWyhD9KDimdqrh806z997u

Comment: The project is not in GOPATH so the IDE will not correctly automatically map the files as it expects that it respects either the Go Workspace layout (aka GOPATH), https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces, or it uses Go modules. We should probably do a better job at warning you about this.

Comment: @dlsniper Can't agree with you. I've created new goland project and added my x.go emaple. Video1: https://monosnap.com/file/Q8CoZwNnoEjtO10HLDiZjmePUyE2Y5 Video2: https://monosnap.com/file/4txmBkXrU5Pg2axOezb7fQdb7334T8

Comment: @VladimirKovpak, unfortunately, neither of those videos contain a correct GOPATH setting. In both, the "src/" folder is missing. A valid GOPATH is formed of the directories described here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces and the IDE will look for the sources in the GOPATH/src/ folder. You need to configure the IDE to point to GOPATH, not GOPATH/src/, and once you do that, you can create a package and start debugging. Furthermore, you just need to set the GOPATH in either the Global or Project spaces, not both if the path is the same.

Comment: @dlsniper Ooops, I've forgot about `src` dir. Thank you! This is video with `src` dir: https://monosnap.com/file/LWCWvfnJyOEjdtaC4TAhnb0CTWQFQF

Comment: @VladimirKovpak `could not launch process EOF` error message looks like delve is outdated. Could you please confirm that you use IDE version less than 2018.1.1? Or maybe you override `dlv.path` in custom system properties of IDE?

Comment: @AlexanderZolotov My IDE: `GoLand 2018.1 Build #GO-181.4203.567, built on March 28, 2018` and I didn't override `dlv.path` because I've found in settings only this: https://monosnap.com/file/GcaRNYTJ1x1RDsUVE43n5EJfocxHzV

Comment: @VladimirKovpak then just upgrade it. 2018.1 is the outdated version, and `could not launch process EOF` in debugger was fixed months ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the debugger directly from GoLand and it will use Go build then delve to run the application.

However, if you want to use a custom build process for the binary, build it as you normally would, and make sure you specify the `-gcflags="all=-N -l"`(if you use Go 1.10+,or drop `all=` if you use 1.9 or lower). The launch the binary from terminal and then use "Run| Attach to local process" to attach the debugger to the binary.

Please clarify the question in case this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: You can add your own parameters to the app in the Run Configuration, edit the configuration via Run | Edit Configurations... | Go Build | your build config

Comment: `Run | Attach to local process` shows a blank window @dlsniper

Answer (score 1):

It's super easy in `GoLand`!

1) For example we have `x.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    name, ending := "World", "!"
    ending2 := `)`
    fmt.Printf("Hello %s %s%s \n", name, ending, ending2)
}
```

2) Set `GOPATH`:

[image]

3) Edit your debug configuration. Set `Run kind` to directory with purpose to debug all go files in directory:

[image]

4) Now place your breakpoint and hit "debug" button.

[image]

**[Here](https://monosnap.com/file/UpNfzqKuv8MHTa0iruoAOnuIejPqqJ)** you can find **video** how it looks for me.

Comment: This only works for single file configurations and your project is not in the correct GOPATH which means when you want to use packages, this will fail. We already discussed this in the previous answer. Also the use case presented worked from 2017.3

Comment: @dlsniper I've updated my answer: changed GOPATH and "Run kind". Does it look better for you?

Comment: Yeah, it looks great! Thank you!